# How to create and add a token to a .npmrc file on GitHub Actions unrelated with the Developers' token?

Tags: security, github, token, github-actions, access-token

The project's local development environment makes it mandatory to have a `.npmrc` file with the following content:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
@my-organization:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=your-GitHub-token-should-be-here-and-I-will-not-share-my-for-security-reasons
```

Hence, any client properly authenticated into the [GitHub Packages
Registry](https://github.com/features/packages) can install our *private NPM packages hosted for free on GitHub Registry* by running:

```bash
npm ci @my-organization/our-package
```

Ok, it works on my local development environment.

Now, I am building a Continuous Integration process with GitHub Actions which is a different but similar challenge. I have this on my `.yaml` file:

```yaml
      - name: Create .npmrc for token authentication
        uses: healthplace/npmrc-registry-login-action@v1.0
        with:
          scope: '@my-organization'
          registry: 'https://npm.pkg.github.com'
        # Every user has a GitHub Personal Access Token (PAT) to
        # access NPM private repos. The build of GitHub Actions is
        # symmetrical to what every developer on the project has to
        # face to build the application on their local development
        # environment. Hence, GitHub Actions also needs a Token! But,
        # it is NOT SAFE to insert the text of a real token on this
        # yml file. Thus, the institutional workaround is to insert
        # the `{{secret}}` below which is aligned/set in the project
        # settings on GitHub!
          auth-token: ${{secrets.my_repo_secret_key_which_is_not_being_shared}}
```

On GitHub `settings->secrets->actions->"add secret"`:

[image]

On the `secret` value, I added my Personal Access Token. The same I have on my `.npmrc` file. It works for `npm i`.

Nobody can see the secret value on GitHub. Not even me, the person who added it and the admin. The value can only be updated or removed.

This feels "good enough" for security, but still, it does not feel like best practice. I believe it would be better to have a "new working" token detached from any personal token being used by a developer who is working on the project.

Is it possible to generate and insert a value of GitHub Personal Access Token which is unrelated to the Personal Access Token of people working on the project?

If yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

you should use [GITHUB_TOKEN](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry) insted of PAT(personal access token)